# How can UINavigationController hold in memory its entire view controller presentation hierarchy when switching tab bar items?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar

When you switch tab bar items selection on a UITabBar, the presented view doesn't seem to hold it's entire hierarchy in memory. It keeps the presented one and unload the rest.

Case:

You have a MyViewController's view on top of a AnotherViewController root view controller, which its opacity is set to 0.5, so you can view AnotherViewController behind it.

If I switch the tabs items, I still see MyViewController as its the topmost being presented, but MyViewController disappears and all I see behind AnotherViewController is a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the beneath ViewController if you will use a modal custom presentation.